# VBA: Efficient Vlookup from another Workbook

Tags: vba, runtime

I need to do a Vlookup from another workbook  on about  400000 cells with Vba. These cells are all in one Column.And shall be written into one Column.  I know already , how the Vlookup Works,  but  my runtime is much to high by using autofill. Do you have an Suggestion how i can approve it?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Dont use VLookup use Index Match: http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/

Comment: Please avoid "link only" answers. Can you explain a bit why Index Match is better and provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to adjust what the data looks like a slight amount, you may be interested in using a binary search. Its been a while since I last used one (writing a code for group exercise check-in program). https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/binary-search/a/implementing-binary-search-of-an-array , was helpful in setting up the idea behind it.

If you are able to sort them in an order, say by last name (im not sure of what data you are working with) then add an order of numbers to use for the binary search.

Edit:
The reasoning for a binary search would be that with a binary search is that the computational time it takes. The amount of iterations it would take is log2(400000) vs 400000. So instead of 400000 possible iterations, it would take at most 19 times with a binary search, as you can see with the more data you use the binary search would yield much quicker times.

This would only be a beneficial way if you are able to manipulate the data in such a way that would allow you to use a binary search.

So, if you can give us a bit more background on what data you are using and any restrictions you have with that data we would be able to give more constructive feedback.